# How can I get all values separated from initializer_list?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I have the following constructor:

```
JSON(initializer_list<myType> myList){

    if (end == NULL) {
        for(int i=0;i < myList.size() ; i++){
            end = myList(i); /* fix this */
        }

    }

}
```

`end` is a `struct myType` and `myType` has a value `struct myType *next`that points to the next `struct myType` and I want to get every individual `myType` from the `initializer_list` so that I can put them all manually. When I write `end = myList(i);` it is throwing an error, what is the correct way to get every individual value ?

Comment: Why are you rolling your own linked list instead of using `std::list`?  `std::list` can be constructed from a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: [This `std::initializer_list` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) should hopefully help you.

Comment: I tried creating a vector of myType but ran in too much trouble, is std::list a better choice ? @Na

Comment: Sadly the objects in `std::initializer_list` aren't movable, that's something you should consider.

Comment: `std::vector` should be the default "go to" container. Maybe if you posted another question asking about your troubles using it we might help you with that?

Comment: ok see you in 90 minutes hahahah ! -sad

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the objects out of the `initializer_list`, and you cannot index into it (because it is not designed to be used as a proper container).

You can however access the members of the list in a for loop:

```
JSON(initializer_list<myType> myList){

    if (end == NULL) {
        for(auto& elem : myList){
            end = elem;

            // do something more with end?
        }
    }

}
```

However, `end == NULL` might not be the correct way to test for an empty list, but I wouldn't know that without seeing the rest of the coe.